# FindControl() method throws ArithmeticException?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a line of C# in my ASP.NET code behind that looks like this:

```
DropDownList ddlStates = (DropDownList)fvAccountSummary.FindControl("ddlStates");
```

The DropDownList control is explicitly declared in the markup on the page, not dynamically created. It is inside of a FormView control. When my code hits this line, I am getting an ArithmeticException with the message "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32." This code has worked previously, and is in production right now. I fired up VS2008 to make some changes to the site, but before I changed anything, I got this exception from the page. Anyone seen this one before?

Comment: Can you give us some more code?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace too?  Knowing where the ArithmeticException came from would be useful.

Perhaps the FormView is in an invalid state or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the stacktrace, its comingn from databinding, not from the line you posted. Is it possible that you have some really large data set? I've seen a 6000-page GridView overflow an Int16, although it seems pretty unlikely you'd actually overflow an Int32...

Check to make sure you're passing in sane data into, say, the startpageIndex or pageSize of your datasource, for example.

Comment: The querystring was passing in a string that was 8 digits to long. Silly mistake that I should've caught. I has just never seen that particular error before. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that's the line of code that's throwing the exception? I'm pretty certain that the FindControl method is not capable of throwing an ArithmeticException. Of course, I've been known to be wrong before... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen ArithmeticException being thrown in weird places before in C#/.NET and it was when I was working with p/invoke to an unmanaged .dll talking to an USB device.

The crash was consistent, and always at the same place. Of course, the place was totally unrelated to the crash (i think it was a basic value assignment, like int i = 4 or something similarly silly)

I'd like to have a happy ending to tell you, but I never managed to fully track down the problem. I strongly believe that the cause was in the unmanaged code, and that it somehow corrupted the memory or maybe even free'd managed memory. (Removing the calls to unmanaged code made the problem go away)

The message I'm sending is: are you doing any calls to unmanaged code? If so, my suggestion is you focus your debugging skills there :)

Comment: Hi, Isak. I'm not doing any unmanaged code. I haven't been brave enough to attempt that yet.    :)

Comment: that could very well have been the issue Mikael, thanks for the link. (Although I have no way to verify since that code I was talking about has long since been abandoned)